# Read Windows Credentials From R

Tags: r, credentials, credential-manager, keyring

I have a couple of windows credentials stored using the Windows credentials manager:

[image: Screenshot of windows credential manager]

I would like to retrieve some passwords via `R` and I am using the `oskeyring` package for doing so:

```r
library(oskeyring)

(my_cred <- windows_item_read("my_service", "domain_password"))
# <oskeyring_windows_item: domain_password>
#  target_name: my_service
#  persist: enterprise
#  username: my_user_name
#  credential_blob: <-- hidden -->
```

However, if I try to return the password I only get `raw(0)`:

```r
my_cred$credential_blob
# raw(0)
```

How to get the password? (I also tried `keyring` but with it I can only access/modify the password stored under label *Generic Credentials*)

Comment: Have you tried the other types? There are 4, I think listed in `windows_item_types()`.

Comment: Well, the types are not something to chose, but depend on the entry `sapply(windows_item_enumerate(), \(x) x$type)` show clearly that the password I need is indeed a `domain_password` and while I get passwords for `generic` types, I don't get them for `domain_password's`

Comment: I get that ... to be honest, I don't use `oskeyring`, so I don't know its ins and outs. I was asking in case there's a bug or similar (though I'd be surprised). That aside, is `keyring::key_get(..)` sufficient for your needs?

Comment: Nope, b/c `key_get` let me access only *generic* credentials and not *windows* credentials (cf. the screenshot).

Comment: Gotcha, I did not realize it was limited to generics. Sorry, out of my wheelhouse now, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I can get Windows Credential Manager to work with `keyring` with this configuration of a Generic Credential.

I put a colon `:` before and after the service and the user, i.e. `:address3:user3`.  I add the user name also to the `User name:` field.  And I type the password into the `Password` field.

[image]

In R,

```r
> library(keyring)
> key_get("address3", "user3")
[1] "password3"
>
```

I wish I could offer insight on why this works, but I don't know!  I inherited this method from a coworker years ago :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but again my issue is **not** with  *generic*  credentials but with **windows credentials**.